# Chosen.js: Elements receive width of 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Select elements on my page are hidden by "display:none" on load. When they become visible, they all have width: 0. It used to work alright on the older chosen 0.9.8 version, but started glitching after update to 1.4.1.

I tried triggering an update on change, but it has no effect.

```
$('.tab').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Specifying width works

```
$("select").chosen({ width: '350px' });
```

However, I need the selects to be of different widths, defined by css or content

Answer (score 0):

Since the width of each select on my page is defined by css, I was able to get it working with this:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    var selectWidth = $(this).css("width");
    $(this).chosen({ disable_search_threshold:10, width: selectWidth });
})
```

This is not the most robust solution, and I'm hoping to find a method that would define width based on element's content.

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the select element before calling chosen.

First call `$("select").chosen();`
then hide element with `$("select").css("display","none");`

Later when you show/hide your element, the width won't become 0.